# Find by clicking any cell or table data, its left and top headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple column headers that spans of multiple column and I would like to find the correct header number/count for the columns. Also some of the table data have rowspan and colspan.

I want to be able to click any cell or table data and get its left and top headers.

1. So if I click the  with "D9:LH1-TH4(H4a)" I should get:

   - Left Header is: LH1, Top Header1 is TH4 and Top Header 2 is H4a
2. And if I click the  with "D3:LH2-TH2(H2b-H4a)" I should get:

   - Left Header is LH2, Top Header 1 is TH2 and Top Header 2 is H2b

---

Example:

```
<table width="200" border="1" style="background-color:#000; color:#FFF">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"> TH1 </th>
    <th colspan="4" scope="col"> TH2 </th>
    <th colspan="6" scope="col"> TH4 </th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col"> H1a </th>
    <th scope="col">H1b</th>
    <th scope="col"> H2a</th>
    <th scope="col">H2b</th>
    <th scope="col">H2c</th>
    <th scope="col">H2d</th>
    <th colspan="6" scope="col"> H4a </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" scope="row"><span>LH1</span></th>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">D1:LH1-TH1(H1a-H1b)</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">D2:LH1-TH2(H2a-H2c)</td>
    <td rowspan="3">D5:LH1-TH2(H2d)</td>
    <td rowspan="3">D6:LH1-TH4(H2a-H2c)</td>
    <td colspan="2">D7:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
    <td>D8:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
    <td rowspan="3">D13:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
    <td rowspan="3">D14:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">D9:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">D3:LH1-TH2(H2a-H2b)</td>
    <td>D4:LH1-TH2(H2c)</td>
    <td>D10:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
    <td>D11:LH1-TH4(H4a)</td>
    <td>D12:LH11-TH4(H4a)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><span>LH2</span></th>
    <td colspan="2" >D1:LH2-TH1(H1a-H1b)</td>
    <td colspan="3">D2:LH2-TH2(H2a-H2c)</td>
    <td colspan="5">D3:LH2-TH2(H2b-H4a)</td>
    <td>D4:LH2-TH4(H4a)</td>
    <td>D5:LH2-TH4(H4a)</td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

---

[Please see this link](http://jsfiddle.net/nathan406/UbsWW/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find by clicking any cell or table data, its left and top headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322299/find-by-clicking-any-cell-or-table-data-its-left-and-top-headers)

Comment: I had an original question and @Vega answered it. However I made update to the question not knowing that I should create a new question. Vega, notified me on that, so I created a new post/question that links or references the updated question.

Comment: Ok, I have rolled back the other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322299/find-by-clicking-any-cell-or-table-data-its-left-and-top-headers) to its original form and transferred over the new full question to here.

Comment: Oh...Kool! Thank a lot @tw16. Am loving Stackoverflow by the nanoseconds. I have been referring my developer homies to join, help others, get help and share with others. 

Do you know if there is a mass way of referring other Stackoverflow/StackExchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was annoyingly tricky.
you can find your headers by using the parent offsets.

got it working in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/work4liberty/fk6sy/14/

Comment: This is great!!!!!!!!!! Annoyingly tricky and interesting! It is indeed. Please save this it may become handy. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi work4liberty, I am having 1 issue with this solution, it doesnt work in IE8 + :( 

I need it to also be compatible with IE8+ . How can this be resolved?

Comment: it was the borders ie is dumb with them

Comment: shameless plug - BTW Nation if this is part of a for profit project i could use some work right now

Comment: Lol... I just try this and it still didnt work. 

if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {                    
    return {} //IE messed up :(
}
else {
    return{} //other browser ok
}

Comment: No profit, wish it was. If your doing something and you believe it can add value, use it and make magic. Just remember me :)

Comment: i changed it to use document offsets from jquery http://jsfiddle.net/work4liberty/fk6sy/15/ -- Note i could not recreate this the problem with ie9 in ie7 or ie8 mode

Comment: :) U know I created something similar but it wasn't working, what i did wrong was just right "elm.offset()". This is good now, what you did took care of it. Thanks a million man.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td')​.on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).text().split(':')[1],
        LH = text.split('-')[0],
        TH = text.split('-')[1].split('(')[0],
        TH2 = text.split('-')[1].split('(')[1];
    console.log('Left header is '+LH+', Top header 1 is '+TH+' and Top header 2 is '+TH2)
})​;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XHjMD/)

Comment: This is nice, but its not exactly what I was looking for. What I wanted was a lot more complicated than this. Check @work4liberty answer, hit the nail on its head :)