# How to get the closest parent OR sibling that matches a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given a table:

```
<table border>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan=3>H1</th>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan=3>H2</th>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let's suppose we have an event on the 'td' that should search the closest 'th' (trasversing the DOM upwards). For instance, when clicking on 1, 2 or 3, it should return H1. When clicking on 21,22,23, it should return H2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at siblings, if one matches, use it, else look at parents.

Comment: Show us your attempt and we can help where you are having difficulty

Comment: Can you use this.prev or even .closest and then throw in the H1

Comment: Have you tried this? http://api.jquery.com/closest/ I swear jQuery has a function for everything. Edit: I just tried it, it does not work.

Comment: The H1 `<th>` element is neither a parent nor sibling of the 2 and 3 `<td>` elements. Do you expect it to know that it needs to go up to the current row, get the previous row, then search for a `<th>` in that?

Comment: My attempt is: $(e.target).parent().siblings(':has(th)').children('th').css( "background-color", "red" );  

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7gc2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a colSpan Header for one of the cells or td's is Spans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322299/finding-a-colspan-header-for-one-of-the-cells-or-tds-is-spans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().has('th').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().find('th').css('background', 'red');
        //alert('first row!');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().prevAll('tr').has('th').first().find('th').css('background', 'red');
    }
})
```

Basicially i first check if you have selected the first row, the row that contains the `<th>`. 
If that is not the case i'll search for all previous `<tr>` elements (Going to top of DOM structure).
Whenever one has a `<th>` element it will be in the `.prevAll` query. I'll select the first one that was selected. 
 Now we select the `<th>` in the selected `<tr>`.

I hope it's not "over the top" ^^

**[jsFFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xvBW/)**

Comment: This definitely works. I was just hoping there was a more "elegant" solution that would involve writing a function.

Comment: is see what you mean with "elegant", it's one big jQuery selector. You can split the selector to make it look more elegant, but it just made one big selector :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure you're checking can cover different branches, so you need to write a recursive function to check for sibling `th` elements and if there are none, children of the closest `tr` element's siblings. Try this:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    alert(findTh($(this).closest('tr')));
});

function findTh($row) {
    var $th = $('th', $row), 
        $prevRow = $row.prev('tr');

    if ($th.length) {
        return $th.text();
    }
    else if ($prevRow.length) {
        return findTh($prevRow);
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pVMeH/1/)

Comment: Hi Rory, there was something missing in my original table. This would be the real scenario: jsfiddle.net/f7gc2 . I just wanted to do it without writing a function for that. I thought there was an "elegant" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Select siblings and original element, then use closest.

```
$(this).siblings().addBack().closest("th");
```

if one of the siblings matches the selector, it'l select the first one, else it'l traverse up the tree and return the first that matches.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin might be overkill, but this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/eVpHG/

```
$.fn.myTh = function () {
    var $elem = this.first();    

    var $th = $elem.siblings('th');    
    if ($th.length)
        return $th;

    else
        return $elem.parent('tr').prev('tr').children('th');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$(this).parent().prevAll('tr').add($(this).parent()).has('th').last().find('th');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xvBW/1/)