# How can I get the relative header of a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very unusual table. I am struggling to be able to return the relative header of a specific element, as per this http://jsfiddle.net/yh6C6/

The table structure is similar to the following:

```
<table border>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="3">Parameter 1</th>
            <th colspan="2">Parameter 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>State 1.1</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>State 1.2</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>State 1.3</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>State 2.1</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>State 2.2</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Parameter 2</th>
            <td>State 2.1</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>State 2.2</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Parameter 3</th>
            <td>State 3.1</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>State 3.2</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>State 3.3</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming you click on the 'contenteditable' cells, how can I return the row and column headers? Please check the **jsfiddle** provided above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a colSpan Header for one of the cells or td's is Spans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322299/finding-a-colspan-header-for-one-of-the-cells-or-tds-is-spans)

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, but yes, that really helped me! Thanks, @Zzirconium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it by doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').on('click', 'td[contenteditable]', function (e) {

        // Horizontal Parameter
        if ($(this).parent().has('th').length > 0) {
            hParameter = $(this).parent().find('th').text();
        } else {
            hParameter = $(this).parent().prevAll('tr').has('th').first().find('th').text();
        }
        $('#horizontal-parameter').text('H: ' + hParameter);

        // Vertical Parameter
        var thLocator = [],
            colCount = 1;
        $table = $('table');
        $table.find('tr:first th').each(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.colSpan; i++) {
                thLocator.push(colCount);
            }
            colCount++;
        });

        vParameter = $table.find('tr:first th:nth-child(' + thLocator[$(this).index()] + ')').text();

        $('#vertical-parameter').text('V: ' + vParameter);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've [edited the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yh6C6/2/) to get the horizontal parameter.
Needed to add a class to each `tr` that contained a parameter name. Also coloured the selected `tr` to make it easier to visualize and debug what is being selected. Getting the vertical parameter name will be a different problem.

Comment: If you check the jsfiddle, you would see that does not work due to the colspans and rowspans.

Comment: @gtamorim sorry, I though I understood the problem without looking at the example. I've updated my response.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Rapati! I was able to get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/yh6C6/3/