# How to get th when child td is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to get the `<th>` content of the clicked `<td>` item.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zrccq447/

the thing is, the `<th>` can have colspan 2 or 3, this is the point where I am stuck. this is my code

```
$('#table9').on('click', 'td:not(:nth-child(1))', function () {
   var td = $(this);
   var clicked_pos = td.index();
   var x = $('#headerx9 th:nth-child(' + (clicked_pos) + ')').text();
   var xy = td.text();
   alert(x);
});
```

i want `x` to be the `<th>` of clicked `td`. the problem is now that if you click on some `td` that shares the `th` with other `td`s, i am getting the wrong `th`.

appreciate any help

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322299/finding-a-colspan-header-for-one-of-the-cells-or-tds-is-spans

Comment: does it help? just added 1 to `clicked_pos` http://jsfiddle.net/zrccq447/2/

Comment: @andrew the click on the last row cells is giving wrong th.

Comment: yeah, just realized sometimes you have the same th for multiple columns :/ tricky

Comment: is this it ? http://jsfiddle.net/5tj1wjdh/

Comment: @Teo definitely not :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated your JsFiddle with the answer found here: [Finding a colSpan Header for one of the cells or td's is Spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322299/finding-a-colspan-header-for-one-of-the-cells-or-tds-is-spans)

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zrccq447/4/

```
$('#table9').on('click', 'td:not(:nth-child(1))', function () {
    var td = $(this);
    var clicked_pos = td.index();
    var x = $('#headerx9 th:nth-child(' + thLocator[clicked_pos] + ')').text();
    var xy = td.text();
    alert(x);
});

var thLocator = [], colCount = 1;
$('#table9').find('tr:first th').each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.colSpan; i++) {
        thLocator.push(colCount);
    }
    colCount++;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from my comment you need to sum up the colspans (or default 1) for each TH until you get enough to match the column you desire:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zrccq447/5/

```
$('#table9').on('click', 'td:not(:nth-child(1))', function () {
    var td = $(this);
    var clicked_pos = td.index();
    var cols = 0;
    var $table = td.closest('table');
    var $ths = $table.find('tr th');
    for (var i = 1; i < $ths.length; i++) {
        var $th = $ths.eq(i);
        cols += ~~$th.attr('colspan') || 1;
        if (cols >= clicked_pos) {
            var x = $th.text();
            alert(x);
        break;
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to keep it generic, so it finds the appropriate table and headers on the fly.

Comment: NB: you can read the `.colSpan` property directly from an element variable without using jQuery and `.attr`

Comment: @Alnitak: Probably, but when in Rome/jQuery... :)

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to get store a reference to each TH, in order, in an array and call the text from the array based on the location of the td.

```
var thholder = $('table th'),
    th = [];
for(var i = 0; i < thholder.length; i++) {
    var thi = $(thholder[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < (thi.attr('colspan') || 1); j++) {
        th.push(thi);
    }
}
$('#table9').on('click', 'td:not(:nth-child(1))', function () {
    var td = $(this);
    var clicked_pos = td.index();
    alert(th[clicked_pos].text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zrccq447/3/

This code is not optimised, but shows the approach:
Loop through all the TH in the table.
If the TH does not have the attribute 'colspan', then set the attribute to a value of 1.
Create a loop for each value of colspan and save a reference to the current TH in the array.

When you click on a TD, get it's clicked position and retrieve the text of the TH at that position in the array and alert it :)

Comment: `thi.attr('colspan') || 1` is sufficient to provide the default.

Comment: I meant `th.push(thi.attr('colspan') || 1);`... setting the missing HTML attributes to 1 is redundant/slower.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I refer to my comment on your own answer - `.colSpan` doesn't need a default because the property value (unlike the attribute) defaults to 1.

Comment: @Alnitak: Did not know that. Very handy. :)

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie. I mis-understood the implementation the first time :)

Comment: Ah, I thought something was amiss.  The algorithm shown here is incorrect.   You need to update it with the somewhat longer (and incidentally horribly inefficient) code shown in the fiddle!